# Invoking a custom method when receiving an exception in a test

Tags: java, junit, exception

I am looking to find is it possible to invoke a custom method whenever an exception is thrown in a test. i.e I have several tests (annotated @Test) and I want to write only one method that handles the exceptions in my way (for example writing custom message for junit etc).
(I am looking for something that is no try/catch block for every test)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always call that method in a catch block, but what exactly is the use for this in unit tests?

Comment: How about using an @After method to run your custom logic?

Comment: shlomi33 -
This was my first thought. But if an exception occured, how do I know where to find it in the @After method?
Stultuske-
The reason for the usage of this is that I want to abstract some of the information that the JUnit sends by default so my users will understand it and will debug easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using JUnit `TestRule` s much like this:

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

public class TestWatcherExample {

    @Rule
    public MyTestWatcher myTestWatcher = new MyTestWatcher();

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hello");
        throw new Exception("ooops, something bad just happened");
    }

    public static class MyTestWatcher extends TestWatcher {

        @Override
        protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
            super.failed(e, description);
            // Just doing my special stuff here
            System.out.println("test faild with this message " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

If you need extra info about test rules read here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules

Comment: Awesome!
That's exactly what I've been searching for! Thanks alot!

Comment: Pleasure. BTW, when you refer to other users use the '@' sign before the user name in order for the other user to get the message (e.g. @shlomi33 and not shlomi33)

Comment: This is works, but still no replaces the original exception that thrown. Now it shows both exceptions: The original and the custom one. How can I "swallow" the original exception?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to re-throw another exception from the failed test?

Comment: Yes, and I want it to be general for every test in that class (or inherited one) so when a test throws an exception, i'll catch it and fail the test with an informative one.

Comment: Currently have no idea how to make that happen. I might think of something later and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If you´re using Spring, maybe you can consider Exception Handler

http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: I'm not using Spring, so this is irrelevant :(